# Get the JsonData from server to another function with cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to use a plugin for a dropdown which takes in JSON data for options values for the selects.
http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

```
$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    data:ddData,
    width:300,
    selectText: "Select your preferred social network",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
```

Here ddData is the JSON variable that has the data for the dropdown. I am trying pulling the data from server using jQuery.getJSON(), I am having two problem.

1. **How do I cache the data?**
2. **How do I get the jsondata from server and directly feed into this function above?**

From looking at examples of jQuery.getJSON() it does a callback to use data inside. So I am not sure how to get pass the result directly.

I was looking for something like below, but its not working.

```
$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    data:$.getJSON('ajax/test.json'),
    width:300,
    selectText: "Select your preferred social network",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
```

Comment: cache as in keep hold of `selectedData` for future use for that user only or keep a copy of on your own server?

Comment: cache the jsondata on client side

Comment: Do you want to cache data "transparently" or you are ready to do something by hand? For the last case use `$('#myDropDown').data('key-waht-you-want', $.getJson('ajax/test.json'))`

Comment: @AlexG.P. that will not work

Comment: i just want to be able to cache the data on client side once its pulled from server so next time when user tries to use this dropdown the jquery does not go to server to request the data again

Comment: @Justin Homes: Try to use jQuery.data, as I mentioned above. It allows you to store any data bound to any element by key. Just add it to getJSON handler and put retrieved data to storage. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: @AlexG.P.  different passing object literal than doing `$('#myDropDown').data('key-waht-you-want', $.getJson('ajax/test.json'))` which will not work

Comment: You are right. I meant 'bind data t element in handler'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the data object to the ddslick argument object you have to work in the `getJSON` callback function as you can seen the [jQuery doc API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  var window.myCachedData = data;
});

$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    data: windows.myCachedData || {},
    width:300,
    selectText: "Select your preferred social network",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
```